# Use of different object properties for same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

In the avatar generator I'm working on I have several button events that do the same thing but with different body parts. I don't want to have different functions doing the same thing, so I want to use one function for all body parts.

Line 14 below uses the object propery 'AvGen.eyes.currEyesNr', but instead I want to use the one for the clicked button. What can I put in as an argument and how can I use the parameter in the function to be able to use the correct object parameter?

```
    1.    prevBodyBtn.on('click', function(){
    2.        if (AvGen.theBody.currBodyNr > 0) {
    3.            changePart(-1);
    4.        }
    5.    });
    6.
    7.    prevEyesBtn.on('click', function(){
    8.        if (AvGen.eyes.currEyesNr > 0) {
    9.            changePart(-1);
   10.        }
   11.    });
   12.
   13.    function changePart(direction) {
   14.        AvGen.eyes.currEyesNr += direction;  // <-- this is now always 'AvGen.eyes.currEyesNr' but should be dynamic
   15.
   16.        var body = AvGen.theBody.bodies[AvGen.theBody.currBodyNr],
   17.            eyes = AvGen.eyes.eyes[AvGen.eyes.currEyesNr],
   18.            nose = AvGen.nose.noses[AvGen.nose.currNoseNr];
   19.            mouth = AvGen.mouth.mouths[AvGen.mouth.currMouthNr];
   20.
   21.        AvGen.addSVG(body, eyes, nose, mouth);
   22.    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change names of the properties indicating current index values from `currBodyNr`, `currEyesNr` etc to `currNr`.

Then you can address required property of `AvGen` by name:

```
function changePart(direction, bodyPartName) {

var part = AvGen[bodyPartName];
part.currNr += direction;

...
```

and call it:

```
changePart(-1, "eyes");
```

or

```
changePart(-1, "theBody");
```

Another way to do it is to simply pass the body part that needs to change as a second parameter:

```
function changePart(direction, bodyPart) {
  bodyPart.currNr += direction;
```

and call it:

```
changePart(-1, AvGen.eyes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an argument to the 'click' event callback, and check which item was clicked.
Than use it to pass whatever you want to the 'changePart' function. ( you can read some data you have in the clicked element for example to pass them to your function )

```
prevEyesBtn.on('click', function(e){

    e.currentTarget; // this is the element that was clicked for example
    if (AvGen.eyes.currEyesNr > 0) {
        changePart(-1);
    }
});
```